# I'm confused: What is the easiest way to define a variable for all functions in a class?

Tags: php, oop

Sorry for asking something that is widely documented, but I came across so many different approaches and I'm very, very confused.

1. `public static`
2. `public $foo`
3. `global`, which seems to be a bad way of doing it
4. `define()`
5. `const constant = 'constant value';`

Am I underestimating the complexity of what I'm trying to do here?

```
class MyClass
    {

    $foo = 'bar';

    function DoStuff()
        {
        echo $foo;
        }

    } //MyClass
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Class Example
{
    private $foo = 5;

    function bar()
    {
        echo $this->foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, stupid me.. I tried this with `$this->$foo`, which of course didn't work and got me researching all the other stuff. Thank you!

Comment: @user1293977 `$this->$foo` would have worked if you have created a variable local to the `bar()` function called `$foo`, and assigned the value `'foo'` to it.

Answer (score 4):

If it should be only available in your class I suggest this:

```
class MyClass {
   private $foo = 'bar';

   public function DoStuff() {
      echo $this->foo;
   }

}
```

if it should be available from other classes you should implement getter and setter.

Answer (score 1):

The static variables are available without having an instance of the class and are shared between all of the instances

The const is constant - it's value can't be changed

The public properties belong to a specific instance and can be changed by any object, not only by the instance.

All are valid ways to declare data, it depends what you need.

Do you need the data to be non-changable? (const)
Do you need the data to be visible outside of the class? (public)
Do you need the data to be shared between instances (static; note you can have private static as well)

Answer (score 1):

`public $foo` is a variable that everyone can access like with `$my = new MyClass(); $my->foo` and can set

`public static $foo` is a variable that everyone can access like with `MyClass::foo` but cant set

`global $foo` is a variable what everybody can set and get like `$foo`

`define("FOO","myString")` is a sort of global that but that can get by `FOO` but not set

`const foo` is like a static

Comment: If you say visibility and link the manual you can spare some typing ;)

Comment: but just giving a link is not the way we rock on SO

Comment: I said some typing. The proper link to the manual should always be added as well (like a "see also") IMHO - sure not the link alone, that would be more of a comment.

Comment: yeah but I did this from the top of my head didn't knew that there was a page for it :)